# Hiding a section of a table in a form dependent on another field choice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to only show a particular row in a form when the option selected includes the word 'split'

I have used a class on the row to be hidden and have got this far but can not get it to work

```js
    
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".split td").hide();
    
    $('#os0').change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();

        if (val == "*split*") {
            $('.split td').show();
        } else {
            $('.split td').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="product[]" value="Type" /> Type:
        <select name="product[]" id="os0">
            <option value="Anodised closed">Anodised closed </option>
            <option value="Plain closed">Plain closed</option>
            <option value="Black filled closed">Plain closed Black filled </option>
            <option value="Anodised split">Anodised split</option>
            <option value="Plain split">Plain split</option>
            <option value="Black filled split">Plain split Black filled </option>        
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>       
<tr>
    <td class="split">
        <input type="hidden" name="product[]" value="yrno" />Please specify year if required:
        <input type="text" name="product[]" id="os9" onkeypress="return numbersonly(this, event)" maxlength="4" class="formfill" style="width: 50px;" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

can anyone tell me where I am going wrong please :)

Comment: The comparison operator doesn't understand placeholders. Use [`.indexOf(searchValue[, fromIndex])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You selection `$(".split td")` must be like `$("td.split")`

and to search for existence of `substring` use `indexOf()` which returns first `index` of substring in main string.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('td.split').hide();
  $('#os0').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val.indexOf("split") > -1) {
      $('td.split').show();
    } else {
      $('td.split').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
td.split {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="hidden" name="product[]" value="Type" />Type:
      <select name="product[]" id="os0">
        <option value="Anodised closed">Anodised closed</option>
        <option value="Plain closed">Plain closed</option>
        <option value="Black filled closed">Plain closed Black filled</option>
        <option value="Anodised split">Anodised split</option>
        <option value="Plain split">Plain split</option>
        <option value="Black filled split">Plain split Black filled</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="split">
      <input type="hidden" name="product[]" value="yrno" />Please specify year if required:
      <input type="text" name="product[]" id="os9" onkeypress="return numbersonly(this, event)" maxlength="4" class="formfill" style="width: 50px;" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: And the explanation for the second change?

Comment: @Andreas I thought you given that :)

Comment: A solution should be complete and not rely on a comment which may be deleted/modified later.

Comment: This works fabulously on this page tyvm but strangley when I add to jsfiddle it does not?